# How can I store a private key as an environmental variable and call it in my code?

Tags: python, private-key, command-line, py-solc-x

```
import os
from dotenv import dotenv_value
.
.
.

private_key = os.getenv("PRIVATE_KEY")
.
.
print(private_key) //for testing purposes only
```

This is what I currently have to utilize my private key in my smart contract. I do not want it visible in the code for obvious purposes, but I do not know how I can do this on Windows. I know that on Mac it is much more simple to do. I may have stored as an environmental variable incorrectly, but I do not think that is the case. I do not know if using os or getenv is the wrong place to start or what. I need some help on this.

```
    INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s).
None
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\amazi\demos\web3_py_simple_storage\deploy.py", line 58, in <module>
    signed_txn = w3.eth.account.sign_transaction(transaction, private_key=private_key)
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\eth_utils\decorators.py", line 18, in _wrapper
    return self.method(obj, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\eth_account\account.py", line 728, in sign_transaction
    account = self.from_key(private_key)
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\eth_utils\decorators.py", line 18, in _wrapper
    return self.method(obj, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\eth_account\account.py", line 250, in from_key
    key = self._parsePrivateKey(private_key)
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\eth_utils\decorators.py", line 18, in _wrapper
    return self.method(obj, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\eth_account\account.py", line 775, in _parsePrivateKey
    return self._keys.PrivateKey(HexBytes(key))
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\hexbytes\main.py", line 23, in __new__     
    bytesval = to_bytes(val)
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\hexbytes\_utils.py", line 30, in to_bytes  
    raise TypeError(f"Cannot convert {val!r} of type {type(val)} to bytes")       
TypeError: Cannot convert None of type <class 'NoneType'> to bytes
```

This is the error that I get after making the adjustments that you suggested. I very well could have messed up setting up the path within the file. I am still very new to this, and I do not have much experience with python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good Day One Will Do the Following

```
import os

private_key = os.environ.get('PRIVATE_KEY')
```

remember to include the following if this is a Django Project in the `settings.py`

```
from pathlib import Path
import os
# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
```

and also use a `.gitignore` file and exclude your `.env` file

I hope This Answers your Question

Thank You

Comment: All I had to do was put the .env file in my project. It was an easy fix that gave me a lot more trouble that I thought it would. Your code gave me an essential piece that I was missing as well

Comment: Absolute Pleasure Sir I'm Glad I Could Help :-)

Answer (score 0):

you need to create a .env file
with following variable for example

privateKey = '123456789'

and in your .py file

```
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()
privateKey = os.getenv('privateKey')
```

and you also need to install dotenv with

```
pip install python-dotenv
```

Comment: This works as well. If anyone else references this thread, just make sure to add a .env file in your project with PRIVATE_KEY=0x...................